# Login Google\YouTube only once

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, youtube

I am building .Net application that able user login to `YouTube`, and get the history and favorite Playlist of user with this methods:

```
    YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(appname, developerkey, username, password);
    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

    Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_history?v=2&max-results=50");
    Feed<Video> videos = request.Get<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
```

Now my question is can i make a login when get the user login details and then get a Token and use it every request?

I want to make a requests without asking the login details everytime and i saw that there is option to send `YouTubeRequestSettings` with token:

```
public YouTubeRequestSettings(string applicationName, string developerKey, string authSubToken);
```

How i get  this token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not worked with this version of the Youtube API but could if you can't store the returned `YouTubeRequestSettings` from the initial login for future requests (I guess it is expiring?) could you not cache the user login details and make fresh requests without user interaction if and when needed?

Comment: I don't want to save the login details on the computer, but maybe it's not a bad idea to do it?

Comment: Just keep it in memory if you don't want it hanging around on disk. You could encrypt it if you are concerned that it will be discoverable?

Comment: But i want that it's will be available to make request even when the user open the app again

Comment: In that case consider using the DataProtectionAPI (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/05/05/126825.aspx) to encrypt the login details based on the current Windows user's account and store them in the registry. You can use this to log in each launch. It would be worth checking whether the Youtube API is encrypting traffic mind, since someone could sniff the traffic using a packet sniffer and see the login detail in plaintext regardless of how careful you are being with them :)